# Where can i find javadoc view source of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have to render an html file in a swt view like javadoc view of Eclipse
How can i do ?
Where can i find the source of javadoc view so i can take a suggestion ?

[image: JavadocView]

Comment: That pop-up uses the Eclipse text editor 'hover' support - are you writing an editor or something else? This is a very complex area, you need to be much more specific about what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

What you show is the Javadoc text hover for the Java editor. This class is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover` in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plug-in. Note that this is an internal class so it should not be used directly. This code is very heavily integrated with Eclipse JDT using it is going to take a lot of work.

The Eclipse GIT repository for that plug-in is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/)

You can also view the source in Eclipse by installing the 'Eclipse SDK'. You can then open the Preferences and go to 'Plug-in Development' Checking the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' will make the source code available in dialogs such as 'Navigate > Open Type'.